# smtp: SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations: No such file or directory

Tags: debian, ssl, opensmtpd

Debian GNU/Linux 11.4 (bullseye), Linux 5.10.0-17-amd64

Installed `OpenSMTPD 6.8.0p2-3 amd64` (including `opensmtpd-extras 6.7.1-2 amd64`) and tried to test sending a mail, but every `smtp` call (except `smtp -h`) results in this error message:

```shell
~# smtp -v
smtp: SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations: No such file or directory
```

Server itself is running:

```shell
:~# telnet localhost 25
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 SERVERNAME.local ESMTP OpenSMTPD
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Where is this error message generated? Which file or directory exactly is he looking for?
Searching the internet for this error message gives me zero results.

`smtpd.conf` looks like this:

```
#       $OpenBSD: smtpd.conf,v 1.10 2018/05/24 11:40:17 gilles Exp $

# This is the smtpd server system-wide configuration file.
# See smtpd.conf(5) for more information.

table aliases file:/etc/aliases

# To accept external mail, replace with: listen on all
#
listen on localhost

action "local" maildir alias <aliases>
action "relay" relay host "smtp://mailrelay.local" mail-from "@mydomain.info"

# Uncomment the following to accept external mail for domain "example.org"
#
# match from any for domain "example.org" action "local"
match for local action "local"
match from local for any action "relay"
```

Comment: A `No such file or directory` error is exactly that. You define a filename/directory somewhere that doesn't exist, often caused by a typo in a filename or directory name somewhere. `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` comes from an [openssl library](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html) which  suggests that the error is somewhere in a directive relating to  SSL/TLS CA certificates. That might be in the [`smtpd.conf`](https://man.openbsd.org/smtpd.conf) or maybe your system is misconfigured somewhere else

Comment: Please post the contents of `smtpd.conf`.

Comment: @Paul: I edited it above. The only file `/etc/aliases` mentioned there does exist and looks valid.

Comment: @HBruijn: `smtpd.conf` is posted. I can't find a misconfiguration somewhere else as `wget`ing a SSL encrypted resource elsewhere works properly (so checking SSL certificate of relay should work too), and even if I try `smtp -s smtp+notls://localhost:25` (and/or adding `+notls` in `smtpd.conf`) the error message stays the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, portable OpenSMTPD is not very well supported. Note that for the `action` rule, the syntax should be `host smtp://mailrelay.local` (without `""`). The only thing I can guess is `smtpd` is looking for a CA file, or something, that is is not in the expected location. You might check if there is something in a package README. Posting to the OpenSMTPD mailing list is probably a better solution, even though the version you are using is not currently supported, but that seems to be a problem everywhere I've seem OpenSMTPD besides OpenBSD. It would also be helpful to post your goal.

Comment: @Paul: Thanks! I got notification just some minutes ago.
I changed the `action` rule and restarted `opensmtpd.service` but it didn't change anything.

My goal is to have local mails delivered through mail relay. I wanted to do it step by step and thus test mail delivery by sending a mail using `smtp` tool. I'm free to use another tool to test - but which?

I started from https://gist.github.com/dwilkie/41ae0c7acc48186e6058 (the large goal), a comment says `mailx` is not needed, use `sSMTP` but this is unmaintained and considers to use `msmtp` or `OpenSMTPD` and here am I.